# What's the easiest way to be automatically notified if a folder size exceeds a value?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'd like to set thresholds for my google download folder and other various folders on my system where I get some kind of notification (task area notification is the best case I can think of) when a folder in my list exceeds a size and needs cleaning.

I see a powershell script option under windows task option but I'm not familiar with powershell at all.

I went into auditing policies but there's not for logging an event based on folder size or size of any type.

I've looked at disk quotas but that only works at the disk level and per user instead of a system-wide folder level.

Answer (score 2):

I recommed an alternative approach:  Use http://windirstat.info/

WinDirStat is a folder / disk usage statistics viewer and cleanup tool for Microsoft Windows.

Also, it is free and open source. We have it on all our machines!

Comment: +1 this is the first free file/folder size viewer/visualizer I've seen. I don't see a way to set rules or be notified of nearing a specific size though.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Disk Quota Software](http://www.filebuzz.com/findsoftware/Free_Disk_Quota/1.html), I can't find a good free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Hi are you familiar with python? Since there seems to be no free software you could modify this script: 
[link text](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216951.html)

for you needs.